# corresponding expression between Verilog and VHDL

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

In source code of rtl, which is written in Verilog, there is a variable

```
event start_simulation;
```

I would like to perform `-> start_simulation;`
from a file of test bench, which is written in VHDL.

What is a corresponding sentence in VHDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an event variable in VHDL.

In VHDL, an event is a change in value of a signal (*updating the signal with the value it already has does not trigger an event*).

Events are generally used in sensitivity lists (the list of signals which do activate a process):

```vhdl
process(signal_a)
begin
  -- do some stuff when the value of signal a changes
end process;
```

If something should only happen on a event and a condition, it is possible to add conditions:

```vhdl
process(signal_a, signal_b)
begin
  if signal_a'event and signal_a = '1' then
    -- run only on rising edge of signal a
  else
    -- will run on signal a's falling edge or signal b event
  end if;
end process;
```

Depending on how you wish to implement your testbench there are many ways to handle the start of the simulation with and without events.